# How to update webview page control value in universal windows app

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-10-universal

I'm working on a universal app to run on Windows 8.1 & Windows Phone 8.1. In the older Silverlight based Windows Phone apps, I could have a inject javascript into a WebView page.

My Silverlight(windows 8.0) code like,

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
{
    Browser.InvokeScript("eval", "document.getElementById('lblLocation').innerHTML=['" + address + "']");
    Browser.InvokeScript("eval", "document.getElementById('ConsumerServiceAndPeriod_TimeOutLong').value='" + _longitute + "'");
});
```

Now I am try to create universal app with same functionality like

```
private void doOperation(Coordinates objCoordinates)
{     
    var dispatcher = Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread().Dispatcher;
    var ignored = dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
    {
        Browser.InvokeScript("eval", new string[] { "document.getElementById('lblLocation').innerHTML=['" + _address + "']" });
    });
}
```

After execution I got an error like,
The method or operation is not implemented.

Can anyone aware with this functionality??

Answer (score 0):

From my quick research it seems like the `InvokeScript` method is deprecated in Windows 8.1 (see remarks in [this api doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br227702), look under **Notes for previous versions**). Instead you should use `InvokeScriptAsync`

Also you may want to check out the [Win 10 Sample on WebView](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/WebView) - it's HTML sample though

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. I got answer for this.     var ignored = dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, async() =>
    {
        Browser.InvokeScript("eval", new string[] { "document.getElementById('lblLocation').innerHTML=['" + _address + "']" });
    });
}